# What is the right way of generating character+digit permutations?

Tags: probability

this was a question a couple of friends were discussing today, and there seems to be some confusion regarding which method is correct.

The question goes: "What is the number of possible password strings of length 6,7, or 8 that can be created from the set of uppercase letters and digits, AND having atleast one digit).

The 2 methods we came up with are:

a) $(36^{6}-26^6)+(36^7-26^7)+(36^8-26^8)$ ... In other words, the number of all password strings with digits and uppercase characters minus the ones having only characters, for length 6,7 and 8.

b)$10*6*(36^5)+10*7*36^6+10*8*(36^7)$ ... in which we make sure ONE of the spots is a digit (for length 6,7 and 8) and place no restriction on the other positions.

Which of these is correct, and why is the other method wrong?

Help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method is clearly correct.  You take the total number of strings of the proper lengths and subtract those that do not have at least one digit leaving those that do.

I believe the second method is counting possibilities more than once.  Take ABCD59 for example.  Did you make sure the 5th spot was a digit before filling in the others or was it the 6th?

Comment: Thanks so much... makes perfect sense :)